# Add asp.net control to calendar

Tags: fullcalendar

this seems like a simple request, but I've searched the fullCalendar posts and was unable to find anything similiar to this question.

I am using the monthly view of fullCalendar on my .net site and need to add an asp.net link button control to each day in the month.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been doing a lot of work hacking the js for fullCalendar, its a fabulous plugin.

You're not going to be able to do exactly what you want, because fullCalendar builds its HTML dynamically in Javascript.  What you can do is to hack the JS, the place you need to look is a function called 'buildSkeleton' which generates the HTML for the table fullCalendar uses for display.  Its not too hard to see what its doing.

You would also need to deal with the problem that the calendar might render events on top of your button, probably the easiest way is to give your button a positive z-index in CSS so it was always on top of the event bars.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you need a button? If it's to initiate the adding of an event or something like that have a look at one of the demos which shows an dialog box popup when you click on a day. This can be expanded into a host of other posibilities